# How to plot a histogram of numpy nans in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a large pandas dataframe with many np.nan values in it. How do I plot a histogram showing how many nans are in each column using matplotlib.hist()?

Comment: perhaps you mean a bar plot?

Comment: Yes, but I need to use the matplotlib hist() function, so it would be like each bin is an index that corresponds to a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to count up the NaNs first, and then plot the histogram.

something like this will work instead

```
# number of nulls for each column
vc_nulls = df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().value_counts()).T[True]
vc_nulls.hist() # if you want a histogram of these counts
# or if you wanted to plot the null count of each column as a bar
vc_nulls.plot(kind = 'bar')
```